# Defining on which node index should be created with multiples nodes

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

This is my Connection File

```
         this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            var  EsNode = configuration["elasticsearch:AcqDataUrl"];

            var NCTNode = configuration["elasticsearch:NCTDataUrl"];

            var nodes = new Uri[]
                {
                    new Uri(EsNode),
                    new Uri(NCTNode)
                };

            var pool = new StaticConnectionPool(nodes);
            var connection = new ConnectionSettings(pool).DisableDirectStreaming();
            EsClient = new ElasticClient(connection);
           
            var settings = new IndexSettings { NumberOfReplicas = 1, NumberOfShards = 2 };

            var indexConfig = new IndexState
            {
                Settings = settings
            };
```

**Here I want to define on which node index should be created is that nodes[0] or nodes[1] between Multiple Nodes it is creating Index on the first Node**

```
           {
               EsClient.Indices.Create(configuration["elasticsearch:AcquiringIndex"], c => c
                 .InitializeUsing(indexConfig)
                 .Mappings(m => m.Map<Acquirer>(mp => mp.AutoMap())));

           }
           if (!EsClient.Indices.Exists(configuration["elasticsearch:ElasticR&DIndex"]).Exists)
           {
               EsClient.Indices.Create(configuration["elasticsearch:ElasticR&DIndex"], c => c
                 .InitializeUsing(indexConfig)
                 .Mappings(m => m.Map<Employee>(mp => mp.AutoMap())));

           }
           if (!EsClient.Indices.Exists(configuration["elasticsearch:NetConnectTransactionIndex"]).Exists)
           {
               EsClient.Indices.Create(configuration["elasticsearch:NetConnectTransactionIndex"], c => c
               .InitializeUsing(indexConfig)
               .Mappings(m => m.Map<TransactionDto>(mp => mp.AutoMap())));

           }

           services.AddSingleton<IElasticClient>(EsClient);

       }
```

I want to pass both connection as of Singleton and call it in Startup.cs as it is going to be use in the class which is inherited Controller for further queries

Answer (score 2):

If you created an index with 2 primary shards and 1 replica and there are 2 data nodes, you will have shard [0] and shard [1] on both nodes (since there are 2 copies of each shard - and the replica cannot stand on the same node)
The node which receives the CREATE INDEX API call is not relevant for deciding where the shards are located

Comment: Can you please ignore shards and replicas I want to do it in c# way with transient can you gave me some material for that